# If you knew the definite integral between every point of a function, could you compute its indefinite integral?

Tags: calculus

So for a function like 2x, if you knew the definite integral from every point 0 to 1, 1 to 2, 2 to 3, etc... Is there an algorithm/equation that could find its indefinite integral of x^2+c? If so how many definite integrals are needed to compute the indefinite function accurately?

Comment: Yes, it's the function $x\mapsto \int_{a_0}^xf(t)\,dt$. Varying the starting point $a_0$ of the integral (basically) corresponds to the constant $+c$ of the indefinite integral. But we need *continuum* many (but at least countably infinite) values.

Comment: Berci, thanks for the response. I don't really understand that as I am just in Calc 2 and not great at this stuff but I will ask my professor if he could expand on it. Thanks again.

Comment: The differential of the integral function $F:x\mapsto \int_{a_0}^xf$ at point $x$ is just $f(x)$.